# Prove that a random variable defined in terms of lim sup of independent random variables is constant

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm asked to do the following:

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Show that the following random variable is constant almost surely:

$$X = \begin{cases}\exp\{-\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n\} & \text{if }\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n < \infty \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I can assume that $\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n < a\}$ is a tail event for all $a \in \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$.

The statement seems almost obvious to me, yet I don't know how to begin proving it. The approach I want to take is to say that $P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n < a) = 1$ for some $a$ (possibly infinite), using the fact that $E$ is a tail event $\implies P(E) \in \{0,1\}$ and that the limsup must exist. Then it immediately follows that $X = e^{-a}$ almost surely. But I don't know how to formalise this.

EDIT: I also don't know if I have to consider the possibility $\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n = -\infty$. Perhaps the independence of $X_n$ means this can never be the case.

Comment: Pedantically you seem not to have dealt with the possibility of $ \limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n =\infty$; it may just be a matter of changing $\lt a$ to $\le a$.  It might also be worth saying that you are taking the supremum of $\{a: P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n \le a) = 1\}$ since $b \le a \implies P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n \le b) \ge P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n \le a)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=\{\lim \sup X_n =\infty\}$. Then $\{X \leq b\}=E\cup \{-\ln\, b \leq \lim \sup X_n <\infty\}$ if $b \geq 0$ and $\{X \leq b\}=\{-\ln\, b \leq \lim \sup X_n <\infty\}$ if $b <0$. This shows that $\{X \leq b\}$ is a tail event for each $b$. Hence the distribution function $F$ of $X$ is such that $F(b)=0$ or $1$ for each $b$. If $c= \sup \{b: F(b)=0\}$ then we can show that $F(b)=0$ whenever $b <c$ and $F(b)=1$ whenever $b \geq c$. This means $X=c$ almost surely.

PS. Will be glad to add more details if needed.